# make LAN clients find my website through a URL

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns, lan

I have apache2 installed and running. I've been fiddling with the configuration files and also found this: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

that website I just pasted there says that it isn't so easy as to defining in some 'apache2's' config file what your site's name is to make users type that name on a web browser and find your site. It would also take (so is suggested on that page) to let the dns in use know what your site's url is and what ip it should match it with, or something of the like I understand.

Now, I'm working on a LAN, with my linux box giving network ip numbers to client pcs and setting itself as the default gateway.
Where should I look for the dns configuration so to setup `www.mywonderfulsite.com` -> `192.168.1.1` (linux box)
*or so to speak.*
I hope anyone reading this understands what I'm trying to achieve...

Comment: You need to setup a DNS server.

Answer (score 1):

See `man dnsmasq`, which says, in part:

```
trusty (8) dnsmasq.8.gz
Provided by: dnsmasq-base_2.68-1_i386 bug

NAME

       dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.

SYNOPSIS

       dnsmasq [OPTION]...

DESCRIPTION

       dnsmasq  is a lightweight DNS, TFTP, PXE, router advertisement and DHCP
       server. It is intended to provide coupled DNS and  DHCP  service  to  a
       LAN.

       Dnsmasq  accepts  DNS  queries  and  either  answers them from a small,
       local, cache or forwards them to a  real,  recursive,  DNS  server.  It
       loads  the  contents of /etc/hosts so that local hostnames which do not
       appear in the global DNS can be resolved and also answers  DNS  queries
       for  DHCP  configured  hosts.  It can also act as the authoritative DNS
       server for one or more domains, allowing local names to appear  in  the
       global DNS.
```

So, it seems to me that you should (on each and every client) add to `/etc/hosts`

```
192.168.1.1 www.mywonderfulsite.com
```

Any other asliases for `192.168.1.1` should appear on the same line, not separate lines. Multiple lines in `/etc/hosts` with the **SAME** IP address leads to confusion, puzzlement, frustration and some pounding head on desk.

Comment: The client pcs are running windows 7. I'm not sure where I would find the 'hosts configuration file-equivalent' on windows 7. the thing is: how do open websites register their address centralized-wise so that anyone, without modifing their own "hosts" file, can access it? where do I put my website's address so that anyone on the LAN, without doing any extra work, just inputs that address in their browsers and finds it the way it is supposed to happen? Is it me or is this something so crazy to be achieved?

Comment: If the ugly, wierd, **Other**, Brand X systems rely on `192.168.1.1` for DNS resolution, you could just add it to `192.168.1.1`'s `/etc/hosts` file, then restart `dnsmasq` via `sudo pkill -HUP dnsmasq`. I repeat, read all of `man dnsmasq`, and for this comment, read `man pkill`

Comment: This is not a Windows website, but the equivalent of `/etc/hosts` on Windows 7 is `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`. Works the same.